# ASP.NET HttpApplication lifecycle

Tags: asp.net

Does the HttpApplication class extended by Global.asax.cs exist for the lifetime of the application?

At what point can instances be created/destroyed?

I'm experiencing application_start firing twice, it appears to be something to do with the app pool recycling and making requests part way though this process. I've not quite debugged it and I dont have time at the moment to do so in depth. So, in relation to the above question, is the following a safe solution?

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static object syncLock = new object();
    public static bool applicationBooted;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        if(!applicationBooted)
        lock (syncLock)
        if(!applicationBooted)
        {
            // bootstrap here
            applicationBooted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find out what your problem was? I have very similar issue.

Comment: @Piotr I think this was a red herring, I think I had a threading issue elsewhere in my startup code and sending two initial requests were sending it funny. Can't remember though, sorry

Answer (score 7):

If you are seeing the event twice in your logs, check that the application pool is set to spawn a single worker process.  Each worker process will create its own instance of the HttpAppication.

Comment: Shouldn't app_start still only be fired once? Don't i want >1 worker processes?

Comment: When you configure the app pool to run with > 1 worker process, you are running in web garden mode.  Each process is isolated from the others and runs its own instance of the pipeline.

Comment: does this mean you get many w3wp.exe's for the same IIS site?

Comment: It is turned off so thats not the cause, but +1 for the knowledge :)

Answer (score 4):

From the MSDN online page,

> After all core application objects
>   have been initialized, the application
>   is started by creating an instance of
>   the HttpApplication class. If the
>   application has a Global.asax file,
>   ASP.NET instead creates an instance of
>   the Global.asax class that is derived
>   from the HttpApplication class and
>   uses the derived class to represent
>   the application.

[ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: It doesn't explain why it's being created or just the event called twice.