# First Web API request triggers execution of Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm having a Web application that also integrates a Web API. Just today I've found myself surprised to see that the first REST request on the Web API re-triggers the execution of `Application_Start` (although it has been run already when starting the web page). After reading [ASP.NET HttpApplication lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394041/asp-net-httpapplication-lifecycle) and [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28VS.80%29.aspx), it seems that the REST request is spawning a new `HttpApplication`.

Further, on the MSDN it says:

> The first time that an ASP.NET page or process is requested in an application, a new instance of the HttpApplication class is created. However, to maximize performance, HttpApplication instances might be reused for multiple requests.

This sounds to me that each request could potentially spawn a new `HttpApplication` and that thus, `Application_Start` must be written in a re-entrant or idempotent way. Is this conclusion right?

In my concrete case, I'm initializing a log writer in `Application_Start` which fails the second time because the file is already being used. I guess in the case of an application pool recycling this wouldn't be a problem, as the resources are freed in-between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read further down on the provided link

> The Application_Start and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance.

So there is no need to write `Application_Start` in a re-entrant or idempotent way.

Furthermore `Application_Start` is not called on the recycling of IIS. It gets called on the first request after recycling when the application is actually loaded by IIS.

As for your error, make sure you're disposing off your logger on `Application_End` so the file handle gets released.

Comment: Seems like my problem was to due to how the app was started when debugging from VS in IIS Express. I can't reproduce it with the current code-base.